# Android wear app : Date Replaces String with another

Tags: android

I am making a Android wear app which gives you a quote of the day, I was going have this app connect to a RSS feed and receive the quote from that but would be a pain for people without data.

So I was wanting to load all the strings into a .xml and have the date select the string.

I just can't think how I would get this done

E.g 
If date = 2Dec2015 replace @string/currentquote with @string/2Dec2015quote

Comment: Please be more elaborate. Your title is a bit confusing. When designing a wearable app, you want the mobile phone to do as much work as possible after which you can send data/message to the wearable device. I don't understand the comparison you're making between Date and String. I guess you want to dynamically make changes. You might want to look at other forms of data persistence like utilizing a StringSet which will conveniently allow you to manipulate dates saved as Strings. Finally you can persist your StringSet through SharedPreferences.

Comment: @user3144836, yes sorry i typed this in a hurry on my phone.

Comment: @user3144836 what i wanted was some java code which could replace a string with another. I wanted the date (dd/mm/yy) to select what string would be used, your idea sounds good I just need to figure this all out, its been a few years since I did any Java/Android work. but i had in mind some code like this originally. 

That it would retrieve the date on the watch then display the quote relative to that date in a text view. ive allredy desinged the UI on the watch just need some help with the code